# Storing & accessing a standard set of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Project` with a field `Type`. I'd like `Type` to be a second model with it's own set of attributes that should be accessible from project (i.e., `project.type.name` or `project.type.attribute`).

A `Project` would only have one type, but I'm not sure what association to use on `Type`, as `belongs_to` doesn't seem to fit the bill. What's the right way to structure these models where one model is a standard set of attributes?

Comment: Will you be reusing Types for projects? Meaning can a type belong to many projects?

Comment: Rails has some reserved words for columns with special meanings and one of them is `type`. There is a possibility that this bring some problems for you so, as an advice, you can use a synonym for `Type` like `Kind` or `Category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: can multiple projects can share a single type?

If yes then `Project` should `belong_to :type` and conversely `Type` `has_many :projects`

Comment: Ah, so I was thinking of it backwards. How would I access `Project`'s type attributes then? I couldn't do `project.type.name`, since that would move backwards, right?

Comment: You should be perfectly able to do that